# The Devil and Michael grudgingly team up

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to recall a co-authored book about the Serpent and the archangel Michael joining forces to prevent the end of the world because the Seal was broken prematurely.

Does this sound familiar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like *Good Omens* by Terry Pratchett and Neil Gaiman.  It wasn't actually the Devil and archangel Michael, as I recall, but it was a demon and an angel.  If it's not, *Good Omens* is still a great read.

**UPDATE**
Per request.  The antichrist is placed by the two supernatural fellows (Aziraphel (sp?) and Crowley in a nice and loving home. The two supernatural gents are trying to delay or prevent the apocalypse on account of them both rather enjoying the world as it is.  The antichrist is raised in suburbia to a rather idyllic life.  Hijinks ensue.

Comment: Aziraphale and Crowley are, in fact, rather low ranked entities on their respective sides. And they aren't really responsible for putting the whole Armageddon thing back in the bag. Adam and the rest of the Them do that. But it would have been my guess as well.

Comment: Thank you for this answer; could you please provide additional information about 'Good Omens' so that the OP can make a determination as to whether this is indeed the title they are looking for?  Thanks!

Comment: @OftenRight Not sure what you're looking for there.

Comment: @Paul perhaps a brief plot overview where you identify relevant similarities between this and the story the OP is trying to find

Comment: In *Good Omens,* the real Antichrist is *accidentally* switched with the child of a nice, average British couple. While the Angel (Aziraphale) and the demon (Crowley) try to influence the normal child they *think* is the Antichrist the *real* AC is left to live a normal human childhood.

Comment: This is definitely the book, guys! Thank you very much!